# SQL 2019 Backup Performance

Tags: sql-server, backup

The setup:

Server 1 - SQL Server 2016 Enterprise - 13.0.6430.49 on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter

Server 2 - SQL Server 2019 Enterprise - 15.0.4280.7 on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter

Both servers are in Azure
Both backup directly to storage account - URL

Backup is done with 64 stripes with these options:

```
WITH INIT 
,FORMAT 
,COMPRESSION 
,NOUNLOAD 
,SKIP 
,STATS = 10 
,MAXTRANSFERSIZE = 4194304
,BLOCKSIZE = 65536
```

I am in the process of migrating a 19TB database from Server 1 to Server 2.

Server 2 was built identically to Server 1, same SQL configurations etc.

The 19TB DB in question compressed backup size is 6TB.

On Server 1 (SQL 2016), the backup takes 5 hours and averages 700MB/sec

On Server 2 (SQL 2019), the backup takes 12 hours and averages 300MB/sec

I am using the exact same script to do the backup and it goes to the same storage account.

My observation:
On Server 2, the backup runs at 700MB/sec for the first 2 hours and then at exactly 2 hours, it starts slowing down.
The wait type recorded is ASYNC_IO_COMPLETION

Besides the version differences, the only other difference is that Server 2 is part of an AG so it's clustered.

Here is a snippet of what happens - Data Disk Read Bytes/Sec
[image]

Are there any known issues with backup performance in SQL 2019?

Any ideas

Thanks

Comment: What tier in Azure is the old server vs the new one?

Comment: They're both Standard E64-32s v3

Comment: Old server has 12 x P40 disks pooled to make a 24TB disk for data files. 
New server has 15 x P40 disks pooled to make a 30TB disk for data files. 
Both configured with 3 x column width

Comment: Have you excluded subsystem issues by writing a 6TB file to both systems and comparing timings using IOMeter or CrystalDiskMark or similar?

Comment: ^Seconded using [CrystalDiskMark](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-fast-your-san-or-how-slow/). It'll help rule out if the issue is internal to your SQL Server instance or not, pretty easily.

Comment: A guess: the new storage is partly thin-provisioned. When you write enough data, the underlying storage starts allocating thinly provisioned resources for real resources, and that slows you down. The next run should be much faster, as resources are allocated already.

Comment: I have run the backup multiple times and each time it performs this way. 
I ran a backup to nul and that performed well - 700MB/Sec

Comment: How does it perform if you backup to disk?

Comment: Have not attempted to disk, only to nul because of capacity